# Call a python requests.session from another file

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I am currently working on sessions using Python queries.

To properly organize files and functions, I separated the functions into a few python files.

I'm going to show you the current shema file, I have a configuration folder which contains:

- `utils_session.py`: contains 3 functions: connection, disconnection and verification functions which allow you to check if the session is still open
- `main_session.py`: use argparse to call the functions of the file `utils_session.py`

When I connect to account using `login` I can no longer reuse the session variable to continue to execute other functions, I have not found a solution to store the session to reuse it several times.

Code:
`main_session.py`:

```
from utils_session import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Welcome to the Session configuration.')
    parser.add_argument('-in', action='store_true', dest='login', default=False, help='Log in')
    parser.add_argument('-out', action='store_true', dest='logout', default=False, help='Log out')
    parser.add_argument('-check', action='store_true', dest='Check', default=False, help='Check if the session is open')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    with requests.Session() as session:
        if args.login:
            session = login_session())
        if args.logout:
            print(logout_session(session))
        if args.Check:
            print(verification_session(session))
```

Code:
`utils_session.py`:

```
def logout_session(session):
    try:
        session.get("logout_url", headers=headers)
        return True
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise SystemExit(e)

def login_session():
    try:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            req = session.get(login_url, headers=headers)
            session.post(login_url_submit, data=login_data, headers=headers)
            sleep(rand_sleep_very_short())
        return True, session
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise SystemExit(e)
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @user305774 I added the code at the top in the description

Comment: use session = login_session()[1] , when calling the login_session as it returns 2 values. Then remove the with block in login_session function and make session = requests.Session(); session.post(....)

Comment: @user305774 Yes but, when I execute the script from the CMD, after each execution the script stops and I cannot reuse the session value

Comment: How are you executing the script?  The session cannot be carried across execution.

Comment: I execute the script using the command prompt (CMD) using the argparse library and I call functions in the file utils_session.py
so after each execution the script stops and the session value will be lost